# Can one overlay a line plot on top of a map in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, mapping, panel

I'm hoping to write a script which exports each day of fish tag data as a line plot, overlaid onto a map, e.g. (ugly combo done in Gimp):

[image: overlayplot]

I'm sure I can recreate the line plots pretty easily in base R or GGplot,

I suspect faceting them into a single output with a top image & bottom image shouldn't be too hard, ideally with a middle panel as the legend so it doesn't take up space on the plots themselves,

I can do the maps (already done, this is one of them in the image above) and making them lighter looks easy enough.

The issue seems to be that the background map layer is a lat/lon coordinate system in ggplot, and the overlay lineplots are cartesian coordinates. Subsequently, ggplot (or whatever else) will not be intuitively able to align the two, as it expects a common system, since the elements are expected to need to be able to interact.

Any suggestions, ideas, half thoughts, musings, pointers, etc, very much welcome. Could I save the line plots with a transparent background, save the maps separately, then stitch them together in (e.g. ImageMagik)? Save the maps first then add to the ggplot [with](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/background_image.html) `background_image`?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: coming back to this much later, I've made the double plot AND got the spatial point (black dot, bottom panel).[image: currentimage]

I'm now looking to convert the map into these coordinates. To transform the spatial object's coordinates I dug into it. The df structure has a geometry column which is a list of lists:

```
natlantic2$geometry[1:nrow][[1]][[1]][[1]][,1] #lon
natlantic2$geometry[1:nrow][[1]][[1]][[1]][,2] #lat
```

I can *nearly* extract the list of lon/lats with

```
sapply(natlantic2$geometry, "[[", 1)
```

But it returns:

```
[[1:nrow]]
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 14.76619 44.92003
[2,] 14.76661 44.92208
[3,] 14.83831 44.88453
[4,] 14.76619 44.92003
```

i.e. a list of 1432 2-column dfs. So I'm close, but I need to go one list deeper, and "[[[" doesn't work in `sapply`. Also it looks like 6 of those 1432 list items are single item lists containing the 2-col dfs, rather than being the dfs themselves. Annoying. Trying `rapply()` with no success so far.

If anyone has any ideas of how to convert these, that'd be great. I wonder if it's possible by hijacking `st_transform` using these conversions as a custom crs...?

Comment: Sure, just transform your the lineplot data so the x/y coords are long/lat and put it write on top with `geom_line`. If you want to go background image, I think it would make more sense to use a map image as the background for the lineplots than lineplots as background for the maps... since you want the lines *on top*. And that way, no special transparency is needed.

Comment: Cheers bud. Interesting idea about the X/Y to Lat/Lon conversion... I suspect that'd be quite easy for X (depth, light, temp) since it's a static map and consistent ranges so it'd just be a multiplication. But moving time window to longitude... I supposed it's a fix lon range and a constant time length so I could just add/subtract the time difference from a set constant then multiply to the lon range. Thanks for the imaginative solutions!